# Generate ServiceWorker using workbox 6 - how to import "registerRoute" from "workbox-routing"?

Tags: service-worker, webpack-4, workbox

I have upgraded my project to use workbox 6 and have modified my code accordingly.
After injecting manifest (generating serviceWorker.js) my browser reports error:

```
Service worker error TypeError: ServiceWorker script at 
http://127.0.0.1:8080/serviceWorker.js for scope 
http://127.0.0.1:8080/ threw an exception during script evaluation. app.js:218:23
```

I have removed code to determine what causes the error and am now left with:

serviceWorker.js (generated from serviceWroker-base.js)

```
importScripts('workbox-sw.js');
import { registerRoute } from 'workbox-routing';
import { StaleWhileRevalidate } from 'workbox-strategies';

const CACHE_DYNAMIC_NAME = 'dynamic-DEBUG-001'
```

webpack.config.js

```
const {InjectManifest} = require('workbox-webpack-plugin')
const workboxWebpackInjectPlugin = new InjectManifest({
  swSrc: './serviceWorker.js'
})
// build WEBPACK CONFIG
const config = {}
//...
config.plugins = [
  nodeEnvPlugin,
  firebasePlugin,
  cssExtractPlugin,
  workboxWebpackInjectPlugin,
]
//...
return config
```

If I remove the imports of `registerRoute` and `StaleWhileRevalidate` in serviceWorker.js then the service worker registers successfully - but then I cannot register routes. ;) I have installed workbox-routing and workbox-strategies.

package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "generate:sw": "workbox injectManifest"
},
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "workbox-routing": "^6.0.2",
  "workbox-strategies": "^6.0.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
  ...
  "webpack": "^4.41.2"
}
```

`generate:sw` is the command I run to inject manifest and create `serviceWorker.js`.

My suspicion is that the imoprts are not handled correctly? How can I use `registerRoute` and `StaleWhileRevalidate` in my service worker?

Kind regards /K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The info at https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/using-bundlers might be helpful.

You don't need to include `importScripts('workbox-sw.js');`

If you plan on using precaching:

- You can run `InjectManifest` via `workbox-webpack-plugin` and it will take care of both compiling your service worker (i.e. inlining the ES module imports into a final, runnable service worker file) as well as replacing a `self.__WB_MANIFEST` inside your service worker file with the actual precache manifest based on the assets in your `webpack` build.

If you don't plan on using precaching:

- You can add your service worker file, including the ES module imports, as a entry point in your `webpack` config, and that should handle inlining the ES module imports into a final, runnable service worker file.

If you're already using `webpack`, then your `workbox injectManifest` step isn't needed. See the previous two points.

Comment: Thank you Jeff for the helpful link and explanation! I will read up some more and look over my code. Many thanks. (^__^) /K

Comment: Thank again Jeff! I did some reading up, and have successfully added "InjectManifest" and modified my config. The project compiles fine now, but I still have issues registering the service-worker. I have created a separate question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65234832/generate-serviceworker-using-webpack-4-41-and-workbox-6